# Debugging UIKit crash [UINavigationController initWithRootViewController]

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, uikit

Xcode 7.0.1

**Update:**

The latest thing I tried was to break down creation of the UINavigationController thus:

```
  self.viewController = [[ProjectsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProjectsViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
  self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
  [self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[self.viewController]];
  self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Doing this the crash is now on

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

but the trace is exactly the same.

I've also tried this with a vanilla ViewController by changing

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[[[UIViewController alloc] init]]];
```

Same result...

**Original Post:**

I have a crash which I am struggling to understand - Here is the lldb trace: Note the index of **2147483648**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]: index 2147483648 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x035eaa94 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03084e02 objc_exception_throw + 50
2   CoreFoundation                      0x034f92ed -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:] + 445
3   UIKit                               0x018c20b2 -[UIView(Hierarchy) bringSubviewToFront:] + 260
4   UIKit                               0x0193daeb -[UINavigationBar layoutSubviews] + 3692
5   UIKit                               0x018d716b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 813
6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03099059 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
7   QuartzCore                          0x0096e60c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 144
8   QuartzCore                          0x0096228e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 388
9   QuartzCore                          0x00970b2c -[CALayer(CALayerPrivate) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 44
10  UIKit                               0x018c4dca -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 1244
11  UIKit                               0x01a117cf __74-[UINavigationController _positionNavigationBarHidden:edge:initialOffset:]_block_invoke + 36
12  UIKit                               0x018caca6 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 82
13  UIKit                               0x01a1178d -[UINavigationController _positionNavigationBarHidden:edge:initialOffset:] + 922
14  UIKit                               0x01a1194c -[UINavigationController _positionNavigationBarHidden:edge:] + 326
15  UIKit                               0x01a12d5f -[UINavigationController _positionNavigationBarHidden:] + 49
16  UIKit                               0x01a1104a -[UINavigationController setNavigationBar:] + 1224
17  UIKit                               0x01a10a38 -[UINavigationController _navigationBarHiddenByDefault:] + 156
18  UIKit                               0x01a10997 -[UINavigationController navigationBar] + 41
19  UIKit                               0x01a17805 -[UINavigationController loadView] + 230
20  UIKit                               0x019d3338 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 138
21  UIKit                               0x019d3cf1 -[UIViewController view] + 35
22  UIKit                               0x01a22226 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 615
23  UIKit                               0x01a21e27 __54-[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:]_block_invoke + 351
24  UIKit                               0x01a21c83 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 786
25  UIKit                               0x01a07be2 -[UINavigationController initWithRootViewController:] + 140
26  DELETIA                             0x0012954e -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 1214
```

This is a mature app which has been building and running for some time but in the current XCode the above happens.

As you can see there is a call to UINavigationController:initWithRootViewController - here is the code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// deletia - non UIKit code

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  self.window.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

  self.viewController = [[ProjectsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProjectsViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];

  self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

// deletia - but the app crashes on the above line
}
```

I have tried a few things after looking at some similar questions and
   answers here on SO.

- I've heard that this can happen if View controller-based status bar
  appearance is set to YES in the Info.plist - so I've set that to NO /
  YES
- I've heard that some UIGestureRecognizers can cause issues - So I've examined the XIB and ensured that there are none effecting this view controller.
- I've heard that if the root view controller isn't fully initialised
  it can be problematic - so I've delayed the call to the
  UINavigationController by 1 second
- I've mis-trusted ProjectsViewController - so I've substituted it for
  a vanilla UIViewController thus:

  ```
  self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[UIViewController alloc] init]];
  ```

Any insight much appreciated; either in what might be causing the issue or in a technique to debug that might throw some light on the issue.

Comment: I've noticed that 2147483648 is 0x80000000 but do not understand it. Do you have anything added to the UINavigationBar that the system tries to remove? maybe try to add a button to the navigation bar and see if anything is changing?

Comment: @ishahak Do you mean in the xib?

Comment: yes because the crash stack shows that the UINavigationBar was running its "layoutSubviews" handler -> bringSubviewToFront -> removeObjectAtIndex. Don't know why it wants to remove something from the array but I would try to fill up this array (of subviews of the nav bar) with more elements. I would personally try to recreate the XIB if not too complicated.

Comment: hmm - the XIB is really simple (no navigation components at all) - I can backtrack to an old version (about a year ago tbh) and execute that ok - I checked and there are no changes on that XIB (or in the App Delegate other than crashalytics being added after all of the above)

Comment: It looks like there is something (in code perhaps) which is asking for a subview to be brought to the front. This I imagine is asking for the index of the view in its parent and asking to remove it so it can add it at the end. The search must be returning NSNotFound which is 2147483648 (The largest integer value) and then it uses that to do the remove. Looks like you should focus on the NavigationBar and any code which relates to the bar. It seems to be in position navigation bar hidden. Is it hidden by default?

Comment: Just to check. I take it this is not built from a storyboard initially, or has a storyboard with an initial controller? When using a storyboard I believe you should not have the UIWindow creation line anymore as it is done for you. Probably nothing, but worth checking.

Comment: Correct - this is a "mature app" - hey it has XIBs I should be grateful!

Comment: @Damo Does this fail in the simulator for different devices and on real devices. I had an issue on xcode 7.0.1 (not 7.0.0) where I had to reset contents and settings on the simulator as it would not run.

Comment: @rory fails on every simulator I've tried and on device (though I've only tried a couple of iPads it seems fairly consistent). Yes I've reset the simulator several times during testing as a matter of course.

Comment: And across all iOS versions or just iOS9.

Comment: @rory - Realistically I've tried it on 8.3 & 9.0 in simulator. The iPads are 8.3

Comment: I guess if you have stopped creating `ProjectsViewController` then it has to an be external influence. A possibility would be Appearance settings if you have any as they affect views. Apart from that I would copy the project and start cutting out build files until it runs or you have something you can post. Have you tried building a copy on another machine?

Comment: @ben-c-r-leggiero Could you give us a reproducible sample code?

Answer (score 6):

I think that you are focusing on the wrong piece of code. As you mentioned, it crashes on the `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]` line, however, what's probably causing the crash is the fact that this line causes the `ProjectsViewController` and the `UINavigationController` objects to load and be presented to the user. Looking at the crash log you posted, this is the part you should be investigating:

```
2   CoreFoundation                      0x034f92ed -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:] + 445
3   UIKit                               0x018c20b2 -[UIView(Hierarchy) bringSubviewToFront:] + 260
4   UIKit                               0x0193daeb -[UINavigationBar layoutSubviews] + 3692
```

You can see here that iOS attempts to layout the UINavigationBar's subviews and then to remove an object at an index that is probably `NSNotFound` (which would result in `NSIntegerMax`, which matches the index you mentioned in your crash log).

In order to further research the crash, I would recommend following these steps:

1. Replace your `ProjectsViewController` instance with a `UIViewController` instance without a custom .xib file. (I read in your original post that you have already tried this, but still, I would recommend doing this as the first step in order to eliminate additional issues, if there is more than one, on the way to fully resolving the crash). It's important to make sure that you are not using your .xib file at this point, as it may be what's causing the crash (if there are any mis-linked outlets or similar issues).
2. Does your navigation bar have any items displayed in it? Again, I noticed you mentioned in the comments that it doesn't, but I would double check to see if maybe there's a code section in which items are added to the bar under certain conditions and removed if they aren't met. This can cause the crash, if the items are attempted to be removed from an invalid index.
3. Try searching for places in your code that specifically call `removeObjectAtIndex` or any other `NSMutableArray` related call that may be called during the load and display process of your initial view controller. Add a breakpoint in these places to see if they are reached during the initial loading process. If so, try adding a test there to make sure that the index you are trying to remove an object from is larger than or equal to zero and is smaller than the array's size. That way, if index you are trying to access is `NSNotFound` it will at least not cause the app to crash (a good practice regardless of the current crash). If this ends up resolving the issue, you can then investigate the issue further and try to understand why the `NSNotFound` is actually received as the index and fix the issue logically.

I hope one of these steps can help identify and resolve your issue. Good Luck!

Comment: I agree that the nav bar should be my first point of attack but unfortunately I can't see any way in which I am attempting to change it / add it / remove it or indeed anything to do with a nav bar at all...

Comment: Welp, bounty's up and there's seemingly no new answers. Guess this one gets it!

Answer (score 1):

`UINavigationController` is a stack where you can only push and pop `UIViewController`. You should pass a `UIViewController` on initiating navigation controller. But if you don't know RootViewController then you can do like this.

```
self.viewController = [[ProjectsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProjectsViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
  self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.viewController animated:NO];
  self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: How would this cause the crash?